# transfer mysql database from one server to another using a php script a few records at a time

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-migration

I have a large MySQL database on my server. The size of the database is around 100 Gb. There are many tables in this database. I want to transfer this database to another server. 
I want to insert around 1000 records at a time and I'm planning to do this using a PHP script.
My plan is to create a lookup table to define table names and insert the data by checking the largest insert id and then take the next 1000 records and then insert them.
How good is this approach? Suggest some better solution/code if you have done this before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is a production Database. So, such large Database while you move data there will be some transactions that are modifying the DB contents.
So, much better to use an existing tool. For this case I would recommend you [MySQL Replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication.html).
I have used it to migrate SQL Server DB's as this is one recommended way and found that for MySQL it is an equivalent way.
Once the DB be fully replicated you will need to change your links to the new DB, and stop replication.
On this way no information should be lost.

Comment: I very much agree with you. Will try this and let you know

Comment: Yes, and also... taking so much effort to write some solution just to be used one time... it would create you a lot of headache and risks for a low benefit.

Comment: I had read about MySQL Replication, before every setup of replica (slave) they has to lock master database -> backup -> copy + import to replica. So that Replication cannot be used to Sync old data to new database instance. Replication using Binary Log every transaction, so no change -> no transaction -> no replication. Replication DOES NOT compare different rows between instances to sync.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest installing phpMyAdmin onto your server and utilizing that for exporting your database from the current server and importing it to the new server. I believe this would be a much cleaner and more efficient approach.

You can download phpMyAdmin here: https://www.phpmyadmin.net/